# How to load a layout inside another one on click and change button function?

Tags: android, function, button, layout, click

I'm trying to do something like this:

[image: Expected:]

When I go to this activity I have what is in black and some objects like EditText boxes.

Once I press the button I want those EditBoxes an other stuff that is up there to stay visible but unable to be edited (that's easy to do from code overriding onClick).

But at the same time I also want to load some layout down inside the same activity (from an xml) and change the button function to act over the objects of the new layout.

Could anyone give me an idea on how to do this two things staying in the same activity?

Update:

```
public void createButton(){
    create_button.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    editText1.setEnabled(false);
                    editText2.setEnabled(false);

                    hidden_layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    create_button.setText("New text");


                }
            });
}
```

On the first click I want the button to do that. But once it's pressed I want it to do another thing. How could I do that?

Answer (score 1):

(that's easy to do from code overriding onClick).

Actually I would recommend enable or disable which is easier to trace by using

```
view.setEnabled(bool);
```

as for the other question I'd recommend adding the layout from the start with setting visibility to GONE and when needed set the visibility to VISIBLE

```
 view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
 view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: Thank you, doing what you just told me I've solved the problem with the layout and unable the upper side but I still couldn't get to solve the problem of changing the button function:

Comment: public void createButton(){
        create_button.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        edittext1.setEnabled(false);
                        editText2.setEnabled(false);
                        create_button.setEnabled(false);
                        hidden_layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                });
    }

Comment: Sorry I didn't see that till now glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've realized it was a dumb question, just add a flag an edit it:

```
public void createButton(){
    create_button.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (!button_pressed) {
                        editText1.setEnabled(false);
                        edittext2.setEnabled(false);
                        hidden_layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        create_button.setText("New text");
                        button_pressed=true;
                    }
                    else{
                        create_button.setText("Second click");
                        create_button.setEnabled(false);

                    }
                }
            });
}
```

}